# mysql vlookup floor

Tags: mysql

I have a navicat table with the following id values:

```
VALUES: (5),(7),(9),(10),(25),(50),(55),(56),(62),(63),(64),(65),(68),(70),(72),(80);
```

I have the query:

```
select 
a.id as first_id_number, 
b.id as second_id_number, 
((b.id - a.id) * 2) + b.id as third_id_number
from my_table as a
join my_table as b 
on a.id = (select max(id) from my_table where id < b.id)
where ((b.id - a.id) * 2) + b.id in (select id from my_table);
```

However, query only applies formula between consecutive rows. 
I would like to query ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS where:
((higher id number - lower id number) * 2) + higher id number equals third id number.

For example:

higher id number    lower id number     third id number
5           25          65
50          55          65
62          63          65

Is it possible in mysql?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using three instead of two aliases of `my_table`, generating a full cross product and moving your condition to the `where` clause? I.e.

```
select
a.id as first_id_number,
b.id as second_id_number,
c.id as third_id_number
from my_table as a, my_table as b, my_table as c
where <your fomula>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. Yes it's giving me all the combinations. I only want

Comment: but I only want the query to show results where formula = third id number. Can you clarify the where? as my example shows: 5 25 65; 50 55 65; 62 63 65; thanks

Comment: Oh well: `where b.id > a.id and ((b.id - a.id)*2)+b.id = c.id`. `b.id` is the higher id number, a.id the lower one.